# Consultar si un registro está siendo utilizado por otro, sqlserver

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, vue.js

quisiera saber como ver si un registro está siendo utilizado por otro al momento de eliminar uno de estos, por ejemplo:
tengo una tabla llamada estandar_de_producción la cual tiene los siguientes atributos:

cod_estandar
cod_temporada
cod_peso
cod_embalaje
cod_etiqueta
cod_dimension
desc_estandar
caja_pallet
ruta_foto_caja
fecha_creacion
fecha_modificacion
estado

Entonces quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que cuando desee eliminar un registro de estandar de producción, valide si el cod_estandar está siendo utilizado por otra tabla, en caso de que sea así que no me permita eliminarlo, en caso contrario se elimine el registro.

El método que utilizo para eliminar está realizado en c# el cual es el siguiente:

```
public object eliminar(string cod_estandar_selected)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = dbproyecto.openConnection();
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction transaccion = default(SqlTransaction);
        transaccion = conn.BeginTransaction();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Transaction = transaccion;

        Tracking t = new Tracking();
        string queryIn = "SELECT cod_estandar, cod_temporada cod_peso, cod_embalaje, cod_etiqueta, cod_dimension desc_estandar, cajas_pallet, ruta_foto_caja, estado, fecha_creacion, fecha_modificacion FROM dev_auto_estandar_produccion WHERE cod_estandar in (" + cod_estandar_selected + ") ";

        try
        {
            List<IDictionary<string, object>> antiguo = t.obtenerAntiguo(queryIn);

            string query = @"DELETE FROM dev_auto_estandar_produccion WHERE cod_estandar in (" + cod_estandar_selected + ") ";

            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaccion.Commit();

            t.guardarTracking("Eliminar", "EstandarProductos", t.obtenerDatosNuevosyAntiguos(queryIn, antiguo));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaccion.Rollback();
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: y que has intentado, para detectar el uso???

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: Si tienes declarada la relación entre la tabla estandar_de_produccion y las otras tablas de tu base de datos que dependen de ella, donde la llave primaria es cod_estandar, no te permitirá eliminarla y te generará error `Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`, cuando se encuentre en uso en una tabla dependiente.

Comment: La idea se entiende pero creo que falta desarrollarla y es imprecisa. No es la normalización lo que impide que se borre un registro, sino que es la clave foránea.